# how to get list of items in a class based on their attribute value

Tags: python, list, class, sorting, attributes

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.name = test

m=1
class_items = {}
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

for i in list:
    class_items[i] = test(i)
    class_items[i].value = m    
    m = m+1

class_items['e'].value
Out[2]: 5

class_items['a'].value
Out[3]: 1
```

I have a test class where I am creating values based on a list.

I would like to get the list items that have a value more than 3 in a list? Or a sorted list of the listitems...

Like below:

```
sorted(class_items[*].value) <<< NEED THE RIGHT FUNCTION HERE
```

to return

```
['f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Or items values more than 3:

```
sorted(class_items[*].value>3)  <<< NEED THE RIGHT FUNCTION HERE
```

to return

```
['f', 'e', 'd']
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to build it. Also, you shouldn't name a list `list`, since it overwrites the built-in name, so I renamed your `list` to `known` in this example. It contains the exact same values `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`, I just wanted to give it a better name.

```
values = [i for i in known if class_items[i].value > 3]
```

this returns `['d', 'e', 'f']`. You can then sort this list as you see fit! Reversing it should work, as should sorting it before reversing it.

[Here's a good resource about list comprehension.](http://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module2_EssentialsOfPython/Generators_and_Comprehensions.html#Creating-your-own-generator:-generator-comprehensions)

Answer (score 2):

```
print(sorted([k for k, v in class_items.items() if v.value > 3], reverse=True))
# ['f', 'e', 'd']
```

You need to create a new `list` with elements with `value` greater than `3` and set the `reverse` flag to `True`.

Also: do not name your `list` as `list`. It shadows the built-in `list`.

Comment: So, next is ‘v.value > 3’.

Comment: @quamrana My bad, fixed.

Comment: Ok, better. Now worth an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class_items_sorted = sorted([key for key, val in class_items.items()], reverse=True)

class_items_filtered = sorted([key for key, val in class_items.items() if val.value>3], reverse=True)

print(class_items_sorted)

print(class_items_filtered)
```

Output:

```
['f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
['f', 'e', 'd']
```